# Sum on multiple columns with nullable values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to edit a stored procedure who has to return the sums of three columns having nullable values. If there is a `null` value, I need to cast it to `0`

Here is a screenshot of data :

[image]

And here is the originial request using the first column only :

```
SELECT SUM(reglProj.Montant) /* SUM of 'Montant', 'FraisMagasing', 'FraisVendeur' instead */ AS SommeReglement
FROM Projet.LigneEcheancierProjet ligne
INNER JOIN Projet.ReglementProjetEcheance reglProj ON reglProj.LigneEcheancierProjetId = ligne.LigneEcheancierProjetId
....
```

Do you have some best practices using the `sum` and `case` conditions in T-SQL ?

Comment: Use `isnull` or `coalesce`. . .

Comment: where is your other 2 column in sql query , which you want to cast

Comment: Why would you want to do that? [`SUM` ignores null values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3171d/1) (basically treat them as 0) by default...

Comment: Sum ignores. That's true. But he wants to add values and when you add NULL then the result becomes NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--ANSI standard
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(col1,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(col2,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(col3,0))

--SQL Server Style    
    SELECT SUM(ISNULL(col1,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(col2,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(col3,0))

--The one wthout functions. It will work the same as previous OR FASTER.    
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col2 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col3 END)
```

Choose one for yourself.

OR you might need following (if you want to add sums by row):

```
--ANSI standard
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(col1,0) +COALESCE(col2,0) + COALESCE(col3,0))

--SQL Server Style    
    SELECT SUM(ISNULL(col1,0)+ ISNULL(col2,0) + ISNULL(col3,0))

--The one wthout functions. It will work the same as previous OR FASTER.    
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col1 END + CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col2 END + CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE col3 END)
```

Comment: Thx for the result. I edit my problem because I need to do the sum of my three columns (in the same table) : 'Montant', 'FraisMagasing', 'FraisVendeur'

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server, (and probably in most if not all relational databases) the [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Aggregation function [ignores null values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3171d/1) by default, so there really is no need to use [`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`isnull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) inside it.

If you want the sum of all 3 columns for every single row, then you need to use isnull:

```
SELECT ISNULL(reglProj.Montant,0) + 
       ISNULL(reglProj.FraisMagasing ,0) + 
       ISNULL(reglProj.FraisVendeur,0)
FROM Projet.LigneEcheancierProjet ligne
INNER JOIN Projet.ReglementProjetEcheance reglProj 
      ON reglProj.LigneEcheancierProjetId = ligne.LigneEcheancierProjetId
```

If you need the aggregated sum of all 3 columns you can simply do it like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(reglProj.Montant), 0) + 
       ISNULL(SUM(reglProj.FraisMagasing), 0) + 
       ISNULL(SUM(reglProj.FraisVendeur), 0)
FROM Projet.LigneEcheancierProjet ligne
INNER JOIN Projet.ReglementProjetEcheance reglProj 
      ON reglProj.LigneEcheancierProjetId = ligne.LigneEcheancierProjetId
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `ISNULL` actually

```
SELECT SUM( ISNULL(reglProj.Montant,0) + ISNULL(FraisMagasing,0)+ ISNULL(FraisVendeur,0))    AS SommeReglement
FROM Projet.LigneEcheancierProjet ligne
INNER JOIN Projet.ReglementProjetEcheance reglProj ON reglProj.LigneEcheancierProjetId = ligne.LigneEcheancierProjetId
```